# Listing all the links of ANY given dynamic webpage with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I cannot find a way to create a generic crawler that can recieve a webpage and list all the links inside of it, the purpose is to inspect an entire domain and all its internal links.

I've tried doing it with HtmlUnit(Java) and with Selenium(Python) but the search of the internal links always has to be indicated by a specific tag or id, and I need this to work with any (or most) given pages, and every page uses a different structure.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) has an extensive toolkit for filtering HTML. For example, you could filter for any linked object that has an `href` attribute set. E.g.

> example taken from documentation

```py
soup.select('a[href]')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

See more on https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: This solution works with static pages, but some dynamic webpages don't use href tags, for example amazon main page (https://www.amazon.com), when I inspect the code of the clickable elements on the main page I can't find any href nor anchors. I think they program the links with JavaScript. But then I don't know how can I obtain those links and I've ran out of options.